# How to design a db for sales that incorporates attributes into products in an inventory?

Tags: sql, diagram

I am trying to design a database that incorporates products, product types, product attributes, which also stores cost and the stock (inventory). I would like this to have little as possible const/hardcoding and also be scalable for the future.

The problem I am running into is that I would like to have multiple attributes tied to a product, some of the attributes would cause the cost of the product to increase, and to keep inventory of the product with all of those attributes.

Here is my current database diagram:
[image: db diagram]

I have thought about appending a 'ProductAttributeID' column onto the ProductPricing and Product Stock/Supply tables.

This would work for a single attribute, but not if two were to come into account.

ie:

```
Product = Shirt
Attribute = Size (small, medium, large)
Attribute#2 = Color (red, green, blue)
...
```

I suppose I could create a ProductAttributeModifier table, to add/subtract/divide/multiply a value to the overall value.

```
ProductAttributeModifier
========================
ProductAttributeID (bigint) FK_,
Operator (char(1)), //+, -, *, /, %
CostValue decimal(7,2)
```

That way I could do an aggregate summary of the total value of a product with multiple attributes.

Are there any pitfalls to this method?

How would I go about the ProductSupply? I've thought about adding multiple columns as foreign key constraints to different ProductAttributes, but that isn't scalable and requires future knowledge of the product.

Perhaps would another table working as a junction with a separate quantity? With an iteration of all attributes? Are there are pitfalls with this method either?

```
ProductAttributeSupply
======================
ProductSupplyId (bigint) FK_,
AttributeID (bigint) FK_,
Quantity (int/bigint)
```

Would it make more sense to put the overall supply aggregate in a view/sproc?

I expect the diagram to handle the following scenarios:

1. Product with no, single or multiple attributes
2. Be prepared for attributes modifying cost (medium to a large)
3. Have the cost modifier be optional
4. Calculate the proper amount of product with all attributes matching in our inventory
5. Properly save the amount of product matching each attribute when we receive within our database. 'ProductStock'

Comment: This kind of question might be better asked at the sister site: https://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Your `ProductAttributeModifier` approach could work, but I don't see why would you need to change anything regarding supply.

```
Products:
   - 1: small green shirt
   - 2: large green shirt

Attributes:
  - 1: size
  - 2: color

ProductAttributes (ProductId, AttributeId):
  - (1, 1) small
  - (1, 2) green
  - (2, 1) large
  - (2, 2) green
```

You don't need attributes in your stock/supply, you just have quantities on small green shirts and large green shirts, right?

If you want attributes to modify the base price, just FK `ProductPricing` to `ProductType` ("shirt") and have a view that will calculate the product price based on the type's pricing + the attributes, say something like:

```
CREATE VIEW vProductWithPrice
AS
SELECT p.Id
     , (pp.Price 
       + SUM(CASE av.PriceModifierOperator
               WHEN '-' THEN -av.PriceModifierValue
               WHEN '+' THEN +av.PriceModifierValue
               WHEN '%' THEN pp.Price * av.PriceModifierValue / 100.0
               ELSE 0
             END)
       ) AS Price
  FROM Products p
  JOIN ProductTypes pt
    ON p.ProductTypeId = pt.ProductTypeId
  JOIN ProductPricing pp
    ON pp.ProductTypeId = pt.ProductTypeId
   AND pp.TerminationDate IS NULL -- currently active
  JOIN ProductAttributes pa
    ON pa.ProductId = p.ProductId
  JOIN AttributeValue av
    ON av.AttributeValueId = pa.AttributeValueId
 GROUP BY p.Id, pp.Price
```

Here I'm using something like `AttributeValue` with fields like:

```
  - AttributeValueId
  - AttributeId (link to e.g. size)
  - Value (small/large/etc.)
  - PriceModifierOperator (+, -, %)
  - PriceModifierValue
```

Mind you, doing operators like `*` or `/` would require some really heavy lifting, because:

1. there is order to consider (do you apply only on base price, or after attributes, or maybe after some attributes but before others; after all 5 * 3 + 1 + 2 != (5 + 1) * 3 + 2 != (5 + 1 + 2) * 3; and
2. aggregating multiple * operators would be a pain, you can't just do `BasePrice * SUM(value)`, if one is *2 and another one is *3 then you'd end up with `BasePrice * 5` instead of `BasePrice * 6`, and there are caveats to using `EXP(SUM(LOG(Value)))`

Comment: I would imagine I would need the attributes in the stock/inventory.I was envisioning I could have one product 'shirt' with attributes 'size' and 'color'. Would you say it's better to create individual products for multi attributes? (I'm imagining a select dropdown for a 'shirt' on product view). I like what you're thinking with the product attribute modifier view. Sounds good on the * / operators as well, I guess I do not have a real world application for those anyway.

Comment: I'd say it's definitely better to have all product variants as individual products, you have a product type as a parent if you want to group them, categories can also FK to the type if needed. Making your schema overly complex will make it very hard to work with, both for people querying the db as well as app developers who will save data into it. Overdesigning for the purpose of infinite flexibility is very often counterproductive in my experience.